# How to use a grep style "-w" option in perl sed?

Tags: perl, sed, grep

`grep` has a `-w` option which instructs it to match on a whole word only.  I want a similar option when using perl with the `-pe` options but it is not clear how to approach the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting "\b" before and after your expression. \b represents word boundary in perl

So if your command is

```
grep -Pe "someword"
```

it will become

```
grep -Pe "\bsomeword\b"
```

Comment: Yes that was my initial approach.  I had hoped for a switch outside of the regular expression because I thought \b would consume tokens.  But it seems as though \b does not consume.   So I think \b is the way to go and for what I am doing my code works.  Thanks for the blacklemon67.

Comment: what do you mean by consume tokens?

Comment: I'm using sed's s command in perl so I thought s/\bword\b/wordnew/ would change, for example, ".word!" to "wordnew" in the output stream but actually I am getting ".word!" becomes ".wordnew!" thus whatever \b happens to be I see that I don't have to capture it.

Comment: Ah, I see, nonetheless, if it _did_ consume tokens, you could always do this: /(\b)word(\b)/$1newword$2/